# How to Zoom in Screen using PagerView

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am developing an application where the main feature is the ability to read articles (in JPEG or PNG format), I am using ViewPager (to simulate the foliated pages), but now I need to implement a zoom in the image to be read, because the image is resized on a ImageView. I took a look at the Gesture class but did not get a direction to the right. If you can help me thank you! Thank you!

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) they also provide a sample....

Comment: yeah already looked, but now I want to implement a zoom in the image ... can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Zoom in functionality You can try,
 https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/tree/master/src/com/example/touch
or
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview